# Do we need [tag:nuance]?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just [rolled back](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/6857/revisions) a tag edit from a very old question that had added [nuance](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuance). The tag itself currently has 5 questions and... what is it? Do we need it in addition to [differences](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differences)?

The reason I am asking here is because I also noticed that the same user just added the tag to [another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/4157/revisions) and two rollbacks back-to-back seems like something I should get an opinion on. Do we need [nuance](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuance)? If we do, can someone please edit its wiki?

Edit: Actually, it looks like nearly all of the questions tagged with this were from the same user.

Comment: (_Ha!  When I first saw the title of this question, I thought it read "**Do we need tag insurance?**"_)

Comment: It was me that added the nuance tags to several questions. I think it came up when I checked for it but I noticed it was only used once so I searched for other questions that asked about nuances and added it to those too to help it along. Thought I was doing the right thing. Oh well (-:

Comment: @hippietrail:  I'm sorry, I didn't mean to criticize.  I merely forgot to add the _emoticon_ to my comment (these "smilies" are fairly recent additions to English that I'm still getting used to).  =)

Comment: @hippie: No harm done. I just thought it was an odd tag to have around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say [word-choice](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice) is the better tag for this. It's hard to define what types of differences are *nuances* as opposed to larger differences, whereas *word choice* covers the entire spectrum.

Comment: I'm with waiwai933 and Occam on this one - "do not multiply entities..."